# Алгоритм Укконена. Линеаризация циклической строки

Tags: c++, c, алгоритм, текст, дерево

Предположим, я построил суффиксное дерево...

Мне требуется "*Линеаризовать циклическую строку, то есть найти минимальный в лексикографическом смысле разрез циклической строки*"

Есть у кого идеи - как это сделать (алгоритм)?

Также можете разъяснить - что такое *разрез циклической строки*

Comment: разрез циклической строки = подстрока циклической строки, длинна которой равна длине периода (циклической строки). Понятно, что число различных разрезов равно длине периода.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если перечислить все циклические сдвиги строки, то [лексикографически минимальный](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographically_minimal_string_rotation) и будет тем, что нужно

```
 abbab
 bbaba
 babab
 ababb //  вот оно
 babba
```

Если требуется именно применение суффиксного дерева (или  массива), то можно перечислить в лекс. порядке суффиксы для удвоенной строки (обход дерева или проход по суфф.массиву), и **выбрать наименьший, длина которого не меньше длины исходной строки**, и взять от него кусок с длиной строки

```
abba+abba = abbaabba
```

суффиксы

```
a
aabba   //вот оно, берём aabb
abba
abbaabba
ba
baabba
bba
bbaabba
```

Кроме того, для нахождения минимального циклического разреза есть простой линейный [алгоритм Дюваля](https://e-maxx.ru/algo/duval_algorithm), строящий декомпозицию Линдона для удвоенной строки  (`abbababbab`), это проще, чем построение суффиксного дерева.

```
string min_cyclic_shift (string s) {
    s += s;
    int n = (int) s.length();
    int i=0, ans=0;
    while (i < n/2) {
        ans = i;
        int j=i+1, k=i;
        while (j < n && s[k] <= s[j]) {
            if (s[k] < s[j])
                k = i;
            else
                ++k;
            ++j;
        }
        while (i <= k)  i += j - k;
    }
    return s.substr (ans, n/2);
```

Comment: А в каком месте здесь нужно строить суффиксное дерево?

Comment: При использовании этого алгоритма суффиксное дерево не требуется, он проще. Добавил, как с суффиксным деревом быть.

Comment: мне по заданию нужно :(

Comment: Огромное спасибо!!!!